# Matching pattern list between 2 files in Ruby

Tags: ruby, list, string-matching

I'm trying to print lines from **Input.txt** that contains the strings in **ValuesToSearch.txt**. My current script shown below prints the correct output,
but when I try with actual data where **Input.txt** has 9.5 millions of lines and **ValuesToSearch.txt** has 300 lines, the processing is very very slow.

How can be modified the script in order to get faster the output? Thanks

**Input.txt**

```
ID       HM    PRAO  LN  AC
1401144  851    2    45   32
1401145  6D2    4    45   32
1401146  B33    1    45   32
1401147  EEC    9    45   32
1401148  730    1    45   32
1401149  C08    3    45   32
1401150  B91    4    45   32
1401151  978    1    45   32
1401152  6A9    0    45   32
```

**ValuesToSearch.txt**

```
1401176
1401148
1401149
1401151
```

**My script:**

```
ruby -e '
a=File.foreach("Input.txt").map {|l| l.split(" ")}
b=File.foreach("ValuesToSearch.txt").map {|l| l.split(" ")}.flatten

b.map{ |z| 
    a.map{ |i| puts i.join(" ") if i.include?(z) } 
}'

1401148 730 1 45 32
1401149 C08 3 45 32
1401151 978 1 45 32
```

Comment: Is `Input.txt` always going to be sorted by ID as it appears to be here?

Comment: The `-e` method of executing is intended for really quick one-liners. For anything else put it in a `.rb` script file and run that: `ruby myscript.rb`

Comment: `#each` will be much faster than `map` since you are not holding on to the output anyway

Comment: You are using two maps in side of each other. This has a run-time of O(N*M). A quick fix might actually be to change the order of `a` and `b`, but the proper way to do this would be to use something like a hashmap (`a = {}`) to do the comparison.

Comment: Hi, Simple Lime. Not always be sorted by ID.

Comment: This should work for you [Exampl](https://repl.it/JgYF/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's create the two files.

```
VTS_FName = "ValuesToSearch.txt"
vts_data = <<-_
1401176
1401148
1401149
1401151
_
File.write(VTS_FName, vts_data)
  #=> 32

IT_FName = "Input.txt"
it_data = <<-_
ID       HM    PRAO  LN  AC
1401144  851    2    45   32
1401145  6D2    4    45   32
1401146  B33    1    45   32
1401147  EEC    9    45   32
1401148  730    1    45   32
1401149  C08    3    45   32
1401150  B91    4    45   32
1401151  978    1    45   32
1401152  6A9    0    45   32
_
File.write(IT_FName, it_data)
  #=> 289
```

The key to efficiency here is to make the content of `VTS_FName` a set rather than an array.

```
require 'set'

vts_set = File.readlines(VTS_FName).map(&:chomp).to_set
File.foreach(IT_FName) { |line| puts line if vts_set.include?(line[/\d+/]) }
1401148  730    1    45   32
1401149  C08    3    45   32
1401151  978    1    45   32
```

To save the matching lines, rather than printing them, use the following (after creating `vts_set`).

```
File.foreach(IT_FName).with_object([]) { |line, arr|
  arr << line.chomp if vts_set.include?(line[/\d+/]) }
  #=> ["1401148  730    1    45   32",
  #    "1401149  C08    3    45   32",
  #    "1401151  978    1    45   32"]
```

Comment: Hi Cary. Many thanks for your solution that is even a half faster. More/less 13 seconds. So there is a diference in the way that stores in memory ruby an array and a set? it can access the elements faster with a set?

Comment: Ruby implements sets with underlying hashes.  [This article](https://launchschool.com/blog/how-the-hash-works-in-ruby) provides a clear explanation of how Ruby's hashes are implemented and why key lookups are so fast when compared to array lookups.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
dict = File.read('/tmp/ValuesToSearch.txt').split.inject({}) do |acc, word|
  acc[word] = true
  acc
end

File.foreach('/tmp/Input.txt') do |line|
  puts line if line.split.any? { |word| dict[word] }
end
```

In this approach, I'm using a Hash to store the "values to search".
Thus, we can search in O(1) (instead of O(N)).

And you don't need to iterate twice in the words of the Input.txt.
You can print the lines you want in a single iteration.

And as suggested by @tadman, put this script in a file and execute it using `ruby myscript.rb`.

Comment: Excellent Lucas, with your solution the output was print in less than 20 seconds, when tryin with my solution was stuck for more than an hour. Thanks so much.